# How can I install ubuntu without a any cd or usb drive

Tags: boot, system-installation, xubuntu, hard-drive

I would like to Ubuntu,but I really can't use any disk on my laptop now nor do I have any USB drive right now. So how would I install Ubuntu on my pc without using a CD or USB drive? I tried using these steps

1.Download Unetbootin from here.

2.Run Unetbootin.

3.Now, from the drop-down menu under Type: select Hard Disk.

4.Next select the Diskimage. Browse to the directory where you downloaded the iso file of Ubuntu.

5.Press OK.

6.Next when you reboot, you will get a menu like this

7.Select Unetbootin and you will get the "Try" or "Install" option there.

8.Finally, you can install your version of Ubuntu alongside Windows.

But when I do that, I get this error when I try to run Unetbootin:

"The application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a required file is missing or contains errors"

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/344803/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-on-an-old-macbook-without-a-cd-or-usb-drive?rq=1

Comment: @Aren no, this question is about an error with UNETBootin itself. It's just misleading

Comment: @xangua I don't see anything about Wubi there?

Comment: @OP Try to run UNETBootin from where? What OS?

Comment: My bad, just woke up.

Comment: I am using Windows 10. And also, I didn't know it matter where you run UNetBootin from,but i  just run it from the download folder.  Would that cause errors?

Comment: @Evol I would ask this on [su], since network boot is probably too hard, and you don't have an SD card. People over at [su] can help you with your issue of running UNEtBootin on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a notebook, chances are that it has a **card reader**. If that's yur case, follow these instructions:

You could use an **SD card** from a camera, phone or any other device. Copy the contents of the card to your hard drive so you can recover them later.

We will create a bootable SD Card.

Download [Linux Live USB Creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/download)

Once you open **Linux live USB Creator** (LiLi), choose your SD Card reader from the list at the top.

Then you have to select the installation source: a **file from your hard drive (IMG, ZIP, ISO...)**, a **CD/DVD** on your CD/DVD drive, or download your favorite distro (yes, all ubuntu flavors are available). If you select "Download", you can select a distro and download either amnually or automatically.

**Persistence** will let you select whether there will be a persistent drive space for your settings, so they won't be lost when yo reboot your machine (in case you plan to use Ubuntu from your SD Card only). Otherwise, the SD card will be live mode only (no setting or personal file will be saved).

You will also have the option to format the card, hide the files and include VirtualBox so you can run your distro from inside W*nd**s.

When you are ready to create your Live SD card, click the lightning bolt at the bottom left.

No matter whether you choose live mode only or persistent mode; you will always be able to install to hard disk.

Once you have installed Ubuntu, you can format your SD card again and put the original files on it again.

Comment: Well, I look at the steps and even though I don't have a SD Card, these steps made me wish I didn't lose my old 3ds SD card. But other than that, thanks for the answer. I will just get me a SD card later on.

Comment: If you get an USB drive instead, you can use it wih Linux Live USB Creator (in fact, it was created with USB drives in mind, but it works with SD ards too).

So, whether you get yourself a card or an USB drive, both will work.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help. You guys, gals, were really helpful.

Comment: Let me know if/when it works for you.

Comment: Does this work with microUSB?

Answer (score 2):

There are [possibilities](https://superuser.com/questions/704501/how-can-i-setup-servers-with-no-hdd-to-boot-windows-server-via-network) of installing an OS over network, but the machine has to have enough ram to hold the OS , and it's typically in the domain of server computers.

I would suggest that if you don't have an installation media, such as USB or DVD, install Ubuntu in Virtual Machine. The big advantage is that if something goes wrong, and you are very new to Linux, you can just delete the virtual machine , and start over. Disk is safe, your files are safe, everybody happy. VirtualBox is what i personally use and recommend