# Install Ubuntu after Torrent Download

Tags: system-installation

Is a DVD or USB required to install regardless of download method?
I've downloaded via torrent.

What is the next step?

Comment: Sorry? I am missing something in this question. "Is a DVD or USB required to install regardless of download method?" Install what? "I've downloaded via torrent." Install what? "What is the next step?" edit your question so it makes more sense perhaps?

Comment: Yes, you need a bootable medium other than your computer's hard drive to install Ubuntu. Either burn a DVD or create a USB stick/drive and boot from that.

Comment: If you mean the Ubuntu ISO: it is best to do this with an USB, otherwise a DVD. But it is not needed. You can also setup a partition to hold the ISO and get a bootloader to boot from that partition. I would not go through the trouble though and use an USB.Also see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/724737/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-a-any-cd-or-usb-drive

Comment: @Jos not really correct ;-) A card reader or over a network is also an option.

Answer (score 0):

Technically no, as you can read from the answers to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59347/is-it-possible-to-install-ubuntu-without-a-cd-or-usb-drive#918) question.
(Ignore all answers involving Wubi as it is no longer actively maintained)
Practically, it will make your life much easier, and if this is the first time you are trying to install Ubuntu and there is no practical reason from refraining from the use of external memory (USB, DVD, SD etc.), e.g. because you have no USB port and/or CD drive.

So the next step would be writing DVD image, booting from that DVD and following the installation instructions.